# Which sets of base 10 digits have the property that, for every $n$, there is a $n$-digit number made up of these digits that is divisible by $5^n$?

Tags: divisibility, integers, decimal-expansion

Which sets of non-zero base 10 digits have the property that, for every $n$, there is a $n$-digit number made up of these digits that is divisible by $5^n$?

This is an extension of
[Prove that for any integer $n>0$, there exists a number consisting of 1's and 2's only, which is divisible by $2^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604972/prove-that-for-any-integer-n0-there-exists-a-number-consisting-of-1s-and-2/2605066)

Here is my answer:

Any set of digits 
which form
a complete residue set
modulo 5.
In particular,
any 5 consecutive digits.

A proof by induction
is not too difficult.

Comment: $\{0,5\}$ looks like one such set, because $5 \mid 10 \Rightarrow 5^n \mid 10^n \Rightarrow 5^{n+1} \mid 5\cdot 10^n$ where $10^n$ has $n+1$ digits and so $5\cdot 10^n$ has.

Comment: Good point. I think I'll make the question harder.

Comment: I would bet that you must have $0$, which makes any superset of $\{0,5\}$ be the only answer.  As $n$ gets large it gets impossible to avoid $0$, but that is hard to prove.

Comment: Look at my solution to the original problem.

Comment: @marty cohen: I didn't see your edit (so my answer was independent of that). Initially, I had a program which got an answer of no solutions, and when I realized it had a bug, the data led me to the proof I posted below. But now that I see that the result I posted is a result you already had, let me know if you would prefer for me to delete my answer.

Comment: No. Keep your answer. I feel that independently derived answers are fine. And I accepted your answer.

Comment: The (at the moment) ultimate generalization: if base $b = uv$ where $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime, then there is a set of $u$ non-zero digits in base $b$ such that, for any $n$, there is a $n$-digit number in base $b$ formed from the set that is divisible by $u^n$. The set is, of course, a complete residue set modulo $u$. Question: is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial result . . .

**Claim:**

If $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ contains a complete residue system, mod $5$, then for all positive integers $n$, there is an $n$-digit number $x$ such that

- All digits of $x$ are elements of $S$.$\\[4pt]$

  $5^n{\mid}x$.

**Proof:**

Assume $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ contains a complete residue system, mod $5$.

Necessarily $5 \in S$, hence the claim holds for $n=1$.

Proceed by induction on $n$.

Fix $n \ge 1$, and let $x$ be an $n$-digit number such that all digits of $x$ are elements of $S$, and $5^n{\mid}x$.

Let $y ={\large{\frac{x}{5^n}}}$.

Choose $d \in S$ such that $d(2^n) + y \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;5)$.

Let $x'=d(10^n)+x$.

Then $x'$ is an $(n+1)$-digit number, all of whose digits are elements of $S$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Also,}\;\;x'&=d(10^n)+x\\[4pt]
&=(5^n)(d(2^n)+y)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is a multiple of $5^{n+1}$.

Thus, the induction is complete.

**Update:**

For $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, call $S$ *qualifying* if for every positive integer $n$, there is an $n$-digit number $x$ such that

- All digits of $x$ are in $S$.$\\[4pt]$

  $5^n{\mid}x$.

As was shown, if $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, and $S$ contains a complete residue system, mod $5$, then $S$ is qualifying.

For $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, call $S$ a *minimal exception* if

- $S$ is a qualifying set.$\\[4pt]$

  $S$ does not contain a complete residue system, mod $5$.$\\[4pt]$

  No proper subset of $S$ is qualifying.

**Conjecture:**

There are exactly $11$ minimal exceptions, as listed below:
\begin{align*}
&\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7\}\\[4pt]
&\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8\}\\[4pt]
&\{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8\}\\[4pt]
&\{1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8\}\\[4pt]
&\{1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9\}\\[4pt]
&\{1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8\}\\[4pt]
&\{2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9\}\\[4pt]
&\{2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8\}\\[4pt]
&\{2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9\}\\[4pt]
&\{2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9\}\\[4pt]
&\{3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9\}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Remarks: All of the above sets survived testing for $1 \le n \le 10000$.